# using ax.fill to fill between x slots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have plotted my data by matplotlib but it is busy and confusing to extract the information. I would like to change the background colour for the distance between green (onset) and pink (offset) triangles.

I used the below commands for the current plot. But it shows this error:

setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (4, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

**How can I use the ax.fill command for my work?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 10), facecolor=(1, 1, 1))

        ax.plot(df["Time"], Right_Elbow_Angles, label="Right Elbow Angle", color="gold",linewidth=5,)
        
        ax.plot(df["Time"], SF_Right_Elbow_Angles,label="Right Elbow Angle",color="black",linewidth=5,)
        
        ax.plot(df["Time"][onset_Angle],np_SF_Right_Elbow_Angle[onset_Angle],"bD",label="MediaPipe Onset",  markersize=15)
        
        ax.plot(df["Time"][offset_Angle],np_SF_Right_Elbow_Angle[offset_Angle],"rd",label="MediaPipe Offset",    markersize=15)
        
        ax.plot(df["Time"][onset], np_SF_Right_Elbow_Angle[onset],"g^",label="Datavyu Onset",markersize=15,)
        
        ax.plot(df["Time"][offset], np_SF_Right_Elbow_Angle[offset],"mv",label="Datavyu Offset",markersize=15,)
        
    
    for i in df["Time"][onset]:
        ax.axvspan(df["Time"][onset], df["Time"][offset], facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Please review #3 of [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html) and [edit] the question. If we can't copy, paste, and run the code, then it's not a **complete** [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the length of `df["Time"][onset]` and `df["Time"][offset]` are the same, you could loop over both of those with `zip`, and use those for the `xmin` and `xmax` in `axvspan`.

```py
for i, j in zip(df["Time"][onset], df["Time"][offset]):
    ax.axvspan(i, j, facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)
```